# Is existential quantification in PL exclusive or modally inclusive of other existential quantifications in the same discourse universe?

Tags: predicate-logic

In "(∃x, ∀x(Px)) ∧ (∃y, ∀y(Qy))", are the sets of x's and y's necessarily exclusive to each other, i.e. does the fact that we are using different variables (x and y) for them imply that NONE x can be a y? Or is the formula modally open to some x being y? Or does it imply that at least some x are y?

What is the "default" set relation between sets of entities stipulated by different existential quantifications, and using different variable letters, in a given discourse universe? And how can I modify the set relation? How can I say, if that is not implicit in the quantification itself, that some x may be y, or, conversely, that the sets are disjunct?

Comment: Is there a typo in your formula? The xs and ys would be ambiguous in the above, because it's not clear whether the predicate is asserted of the inner or outer variable in the left side of the conjunction, and there's no scope for x that attaches in the right.

Comment: Absolutely a typo (or rather two), thanks. I believe I corrected them now.

Comment: Your formula is still not correct. Each variable should be bound by one quantifier. To answer your point though, two quantified variables are not exclusive by default, so, e.g. (∃x)Fx ∧ (∃y)Gy does not exclude that a single thing is both F and G. To represent that, you can use the identity predicate, e.g. (∃x)(∃y)(Fx ∧ Gy ∧ ¬(x = y)) expresses that there is a thing that is F, and a different thing that is G, while (∀x)(∀y)((Fx ∧ Gy) → ¬(x = y))) expresses that nothing is both F and G.

Comment: It's a bit of a stretch of syntax, but I'm reading that as "forall x / exists x, Px"; that is, the author doesn't particularly mind which quantifier we use in the given example.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. In first order predicate logic there is a standard set in the interpreting model called the Domain. All quantification ranges over the same domain - every x being P could include elements of the domain that are also Q, and nothing about quantifying over Qs on the right is restricted by bindings on your quantifying over Ps on the left. So, when we’re talking about “the Ps” in our model, this is always a subset of the domain, and same for the Qs.

This gets a little different in Higher Order logics, where we might allow quantifiers over sets or set-like collections and quantification might be limited to the elements that are in the Extension/set/collection denoted by higher order variables, but much of the point of First order predicate logic is exactly to avoid any kind of ambiguity over what the range of each quantifier is.

To quote Quine, in standard first order predicate logic, “to be is to be the value of a variable”, and variables in quantifiers are always and only members of “all the stuff that exists”.

If you’re looking to define the Union of Ps and Qs, this is the disjunct ‘Px v Qx’, and the intersection is the conjunct ‘Px ^ Qx’.